# how to set a default for BLOB datatype

Tags: mysql, image, phpmyadmin

I want to take an image from the user into my database and use a default if not provided by the user. I am using `BLOB` datatype but I am not able to set a default image.

Comment: post the code you have tried.

Comment: You........cant